# UIScrollView resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I'm very new in iOS development. Sorry for my English. I'm trying to make simple form, multi-view, universal app.But I have a serious problem with my scrollView. I'm adding my pages 
(4 count) via `addSubview:` method and everything is run good, but when I rotate device everything becomes to a completely mess. I think that I don't resize my ScrollView correctly. What is the best approach in my case? I'm using **Xcode5**. This is the piece of code where I add my subViews.

```
-(void)scrollViewResize{
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)animated:NO];
    [scrollView setContentSize:currentView1.frame.size];
    [scrollView addSubview:currentView1];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
  [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
  self.scrollView.contentSize = self.testView.frame.size;
 }
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/n281.png/  - when I Run in Landscape mode

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/21ma.png/  -  when I Run in Landscape mode and rotate to portrait

If I Run my app in portrait and then I rotate in Landscape it works fine for 1st subView.

Comment: Enable Autoresize mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated that you're new to iOS programming then you should read some tutorials about **Autoresize mask** .  **Autoresize mask** is good solution in your case.

http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/working-with-the-iphone-5-display/

Comment: I set up my Autoresize mask and it still does not resize properly it applies only for one of subViews in ScrollView and when I run my app in landscape the subview is appear in left side of screen. Can you show me how to do it properly. I will be very grateful.

Comment: check of scrollview's `autoresize subview` property is on or off. [from Interface builder]

Comment: could you update your question with both orientation screenshots ?

Comment: change `orientation` of `ViewController` to `Landscape` from `Interface Builder` & check how your view does look ?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I tried to made scrollView for each page but when I add scrollView like a subView, it doesn't scrolls :D